# Blender rendering blank videos

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, video

I am seeing a strange behavior with Blender. Let me explain the detailed workflow of what I do.

1. I use OBS studio to record my screen and audio. The output is
   produced in mp4 file.
2. I edit the video in blender.
3. Final step render the video to produce the final output.

The steps are pretty easy. Everything was working till now and suddenly I am seeing blender is rendering blank video with audio (Preview works just fine). There is no picture at all, its just dark black video. I tried few options and here is the observation

1. It is happening with videos recorded recently (there was no change in the obs configuration though)
2. If I render the raw video in after effects/handbrake etc and use that file in blender to render the video again, it still doesn't work.
3. Old videos are rendering without any problems.

I am totally clueless and not sure what to do. Tried uninstalling and reinstalling blender but that didn't help either. Here are my settings for blender
[image]

**Update:** The problem was occurring due to change in Output Quality setting. I changed it from "Lossless" > "Perceptually lossless".

Comment: I realized late night that there is one difference in the Project settings - Output quality. In earlier projects, it was set to Perpetual lossless. I will try to change the setting and re-render again.

Comment: Maybe you can provide a blend file with nothing important on it, so we can experiment and try to find a solution more quickly to help you? Maybe it is a project settings you mislooked. You can upload blend files here and link to this question like an image: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I realized that the problem was happening due to Output quality setting. I change it from "Lossless" > "Perceptually lossless" and it worked.